# split one column value into multiple - sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a users table in my Postgres database.
`users(id,firstName,lastName,address)`

```
   id  firstName    lastName    address
   15  John_Doe     ---         address of JD
   16  Sam          Doe         address od SD
   17  Mat_Doe_Xyz  ---         address of Mat
```

Now I need to split firstName by '_' and put the second part(rest of the string) in lastName column.
output should be like this,

```
   id  firstName    lastName    address
   15  John         Doe         address of JD
   16  Sam          Doe         address od SD
   17  Mat          Doe_Xyz     address of Mat
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this using SQL?

Something like an update query:

```
update users usr
set "firstName" = select(string_to_array("firstName",' '))[1] from usr1 where usr.id = usr1.id, "lastName" = select(string_to_array("firstName",' '))[2] from usr2  where usr.id = usr2.id
where usr.id = 7149
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to update all rows where the name has xxx_yyy_zzz or xxx_yyy format and surname is null then you can use this:

```
update users
set firstName = left(firstname, position('_' in firstname) - 1),
    lastName = case when position('_' in substr(firstname, position('_' in firstname)+1)) = 0
                         and lastName is null 
                    then substr(substr(firstname, position('_' in firstname)+1), 0)
                    when lastName is null 
                    then substr(substr(firstname, position('_' in firstname)+1), 0, position('_' in substr(firstname, position('_' in firstname)+1)))
                    else lastName 
               end
where position('_' in firstname) > 0 ;
```

This will not update over the already existing surname. Also it will take only the second part of the firstname format.

[Here is a DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ceadf14bb7125dd4d07bd58d9d4af7c3) to put it in perspective for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
update users usr
    set firstName = left(firstname, position('_' in firstname) - 1),
        lastName = substr(firstname, position('_' in firstname) + 1)
where usr.id = 7149 and position('_' in firstname) > 0;
```